# Golang client library support for Apache Airflow

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Google cloud composer which essentially gives you an Apache Airflow environment. Since my application is written in Golang, I was looking for a golang client library to create and execute DAGs in the Cloud Composer Airflow environment. Please let me know if there's any.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to write DAGs using Go? Or create a DAG from your Go application? Or run Go code as a task in your DAG?

Comment: @norbjd I need to do all the three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your clarification, you can't! Indeed, Composer is a managed version of [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), where dags are described in Python and in Python only.

You can reach the Composer/Airflow API with Go, you can generate Python code with Go and Go template. You can also define a [custom Operator in Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) which run a Go binary with the right parameters. However, the custom operator itself must be wrote in Python.

Comment: How did you pushed go binaries to airflow?
Did you gsutil'ed it to {bucket_path}/data/ ?

Comment: @Xao, yes it's the easiest. But create a folder with  your binary and another one with your data to not mix both!

Comment: Found this https://github.com/svrakitin/airflow-golang-plugin implementation. Seems promising.